# How to launch rviz2 using urdf like urdf_tutorial of ROS1

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I want to make my robot arm with to use urdf on ROS2.
However, I can't find lanch file like urdf_tutorial of ROS1 and use rviz from command line with urdf.
I know that ROS2's launch file is writen by python but urdf_tutorial of ROS1 is written by XML file.
In addition, I know  ROS2'launch is beta vertion.
How do I do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328496/how-to-launch-rviz2-using-urdf-like-urdf_tutorial-of-ros1./) by [sumi](https://answers.ros.org/users/44056/sumi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The urdf tutorial of ros1 gives you a node that let's you view your urdf file, yes?

I was able to view my urdf file by running rviz2:

```
ros2 run rviz2 rviz2
```

and then adding a RobotModel plugin, and setting the Description File variable to the path to my urdf file.

Then I saved off this .rviz file and launched rviz with it in the future with the command:

```
ros2 run rviz2 rviz2 -d *path/to/rviz_config_file*
```

---

Originally posted by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) with karma: 553 on 2019-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rasmusan001](https://answers.ros.org/users/51468/rasmusan001/) on 2020-02-04**:
Just a note to the last command; it should be:
ros2 run rviz2 rviz2 -d path/to/rviz_config_file
... not urdf_file.

**Comment by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) on 2020-02-04**:
thanks for the catch, I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that this an old question, but I make a project with a launch to run a robot arm so I put here.

https://github.com/olmerg/lesson_urdf

This project implements a 3D planar robot in urdf. It also contain a launch with a robot_state_publisher and a joint_state_publisher_gui. It also configure the rviz with tf and robotModel plugin to view the robot.

---

Originally posted by [remlog](https://answers.ros.org/users/3008/remlog/) with karma: 66 on 2020-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer by @johnconn is valid, but it is missing `joint_state_publisher_gui` and `joint_state_publisher` which you may need.

Unfortunately, `urdf_tutorial` is not available as a Debian package, but you can install it from `ros2` branch:
https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/tree/ros2

```
# Source ROS2 environment
git clone -b ros2 https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial.git src/urdf_tutorial
colcon build --packages-select urdf_tutorial

# You may need to install `joint-state-publisher`
sudo apt install ros-foxy-joint-state-publisher-gui os-foxy-joint-state-publisher
```

And use it as:

```
ros2 launch urdf_tutorial display.launch.py model:=/path/to/your/urdf
```

You can also copy the launch file in your package:
https://github.com/ros/urdf_tutorial/blob/ros2/launch/display.launch.py

---

Originally posted by [lukicdarkoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44970/lukicdarkoo/) with karma: 486 on 2020-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peterb](https://answers.ros.org/users/50439/peterb/) on 2021-04-30**:
I also needed to install ros-foxy-xacro package:
sudo apt install ros-foxy-xacro